# Serilog is missing log file entries for my ASP VB.NET web project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, serilog

The following code works fine for one user on the web site. 
However as soon an multiple users start logging in simultaneously, Serilog starts missing log file entries. Anybody know what I am missing please?

```
Public Class cLogger
    Public Shared gSerilogger As ILogger = Nothing
    Public Shared gblSeriLock As New Object

   Public Shared Sub DoSerilog(ByVal sLogMessage As String)
        SyncLock gblSeriLock
            If gSerilogger Is Nothing Then
                gSerilogger = New LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().WriteTo.File("d:\Logfiles\SERI.log").CreateLogger()
            End If
            gSerilogger.Information(sLogMessage)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage example:

```
cLogger.DoSerilog("Test")
```